# Need of the DoD for a heavy lift vehicle for "other" satellites

Tags: launch, history, mission-design, military, saturn-i

As mentioned in Saturn I history, the DoD wanted a launch vehicle to put A): 20,000 to 40,000 pounds (~9,100 to ~18,200 kg) into orbit, or B): accelerating 13,200 to 26,200 pounds (6,000 to 11,900 kg) to trans-lunar injection.

In both cases the lower end is about half the upper.

In each case, did the DoD expect that one single engine / (first stage of the rocket) could meet both the values?

If yes, considering that the hardware would remain same, would a design which is cable of meeting the upper values be **underutilized** for the lower end values? Or was the target load specification a broad range and anything solution with a capacity between the two values would have been acceptable?

Comment: LEO and TLI are totally different orbits. DoD's requirement aside, a real Saturn V can send 3 times more mass to LEO than TLI. Your case A and case B are essentially the same thing.

Comment: @user 3528438, there are two values mentioned in both cases. The bigger one is almost double of the smaller one. So the question is whether the same vehicle was suitable for both these values.

Comment: @Niranjan I've made some edits to the wording of your question and adjusted the tags. I don' think it affects the meaning or purpose but please have a look to make sure it's still okay. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the "20,000 to 40,000 pounds to LEO" requirement was intended to solicit proposals for launcher families or launchers that could be upgraded from the low end of the range to the high end. In other words, the requirement meant "we want 20,000 pounds to LEO soon, and will probably want 40,000 pounds to LEO later, so give us options for the future."

In fact, the Saturn I and Saturn IB managed to cover this range nicely. The two launchers used very similar first stages, but upgrading the second stage to a much larger design with a more powerful engine more than doubled the LEO payload capability of the rocket.