# US DoD's need for a heavy lift vehicle, leading to Saturn I

Tags: hllv, saturn-i

I read that **von Braun** & his team at ABMA had **started to work upon a big rocket in April / May 1957**, which was to have a thrust of 1500000 lbf (1.5 Mi. lbf). It is said that Saturn I was started to fulfill US **DoD's need for a heavy lift vehicle**, to launch A): 20,000 to 40,000 pounds (~9,100 to ~18,200 kg) into orbit, or B): accelerating 13,200 to 26,200 pounds (6,000 to 11,900 kg) to trans-lunar injection. However the **ARPA order** based on which work on Saturn I started, **was issued on 15th Aug. 1958**. The question is: **Does this ARPA order**,and **DoD's expression of need to have a heavy lift vehicle**, and **work by von Braun, which he started in April/May 1957, have any common link**? *If yes*, **what is their chronology**?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53584/6944

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53576/6944

Comment: While the use of bold can be useful in a question, the mixture of bold and non-bold in the current format of this question makes it hard to read.  Please consider editing the formatting of this question.